# How to read an RSA public key from a its PEM format string using the OpenSSL API?

Tags: c++, c, openssl, pem

I could use the `PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY` function to easily read a PEM *file*. However, I have a public key that I have built into the executable and I would prefer not to make a temporary file. Reading on this example/tutorial: http://hayageek.com/rsa-encryption-decryption-openssl-c/ I came up with the following solution:

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

#include <QFile>
#include <QByteArray>

#include <stdexcept>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>

RSA* createRSA(const char* key)
{
    RSA *rsa = nullptr;
    BIO *keybio ;
    keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key, -1); // !!!
    if (!keybio)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create key BIO");
    }
    rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);  // !!!
    if(!rsa )   
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create RSA");
    }
    BIO_free(keybio); // !!!
    return rsa;
}

int main()
{
    QFile publicKeyFile(":/public.pem");
    publicKeyFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    auto data = publicKeyFile.readAll();

    RSA* rsa = createRSA(data.data());

    EVP_PKEY* verificationKey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    auto rc = EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(verificationKey, RSAPublicKey_dup(rsa));
    assert(rc == 1);

    if(verificationKey)
        EVP_PKEY_free(verificationKey);

    return 0;
}
```

However I have a lot of doubts:

1. The `BIO_new_mem_buf` takes a `const void*` parameter, can I just pass a `const char*`? I did not figure it out even from the [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bio_new_mem_buf).
2. When calling the `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY` function, the original example calls it like this:
   `rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);`
   which I do not understand even after reading the [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pem_read_bio_rsa_pubkey). I believe that I should pass `nullptr` as the second argument.
3. Should I call `RSA_free` on the returned `RSA` pointer? `valgrind` does not see a memory leak whether I do it or not.
4. Should I call `BIO_free(keybio);` after I am done with the `BIO`? `valgrind` sees a memory leak if I do not, and in the tutorial this call was missing. If I call `BIO_free(keybio);` it would imply that `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY` copied the data from the `BIO` rather than just linking to it. But if that were the case, shouldn't I free the `RSA`?

Any advice is warmly appreciated. I do not know what is real anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers to each of your questions:

1. Yes, you can pass a `const char*`, it is cast.
2. `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY` creates allocates the RSA structure for you. The argument (if not null) is used to store the pointer to it, which will be the same as the return value. It is used for simplified coding: `if (!PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, &rsa, nullptr, nullptr)) { /* error */ }`
3. Yes, you have to release it using `RSA_free`.
4. Yes, you have to release it too.

P.S.: OpenSSL documentation is a bit tricky because there are many similar functions that only vary in algorithm, structures or data format. At the end of the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pem_read_bio_rsa_pubkey) there is a *Description* section where they are explained, removing the specifics of each variation. But yes, it is quite difficult to find it out with out a good tutorial or examples.